# Display all data from last week?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to get values spanning from last week?

I've tried using this query, but it doesn't seem to be returning anything.

```
  SELECT emp.firstName, emp.lastName, r.destination, r.tripDate, de.departmentName, c.manufacturer, c.yearMake, c.model, c.color FROM employee emp INNER JOIN reservations r INNER JOIN driver d INNER JOIN departments de INNER JOIN cars c WHERE emp.employeeID = d.employeeID AND r.licenseID = d.licenseID AND r.departmentID = de.departmentID AND r.carID = c.id AND r.statusID = 3 AND YEARWEEK(r.tripDate)=YEARWEEK(NOW())
```

This is the current table where I wanted to the data, table reservation:
[image]

I've already added an entry dated on May 11, but y query didn't return even that single entry.

Comment: Does the table hold future data?

Comment: Future data as in?

Comment: As in The Future. E.g tomorrow

Comment: No, only holds past data(today, and the the days before that).

Comment: I think it would be useful to provide a sample data set and a desired result, pretending that today is 11th May - which it is.

Comment: Let's say I have a table named reservations with id, date tripDate, and varchar description. I have a data set there with id 1, 2017-05-17, and "fishing" as one of the database entries.

Comment: You can do better than that. And there's an edit button above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl
WHERE DATE(r.tripDate) >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND DATE(r.tripDate) < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to recognize curdate , it's CURRENT_DATE here.

Comment: Yes, check this: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-curdate-function.php